# How do I prove that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \text{sinc}(n-a)\text{sinc}(n-b) = \operatorname{sinc}(b-a)$?

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, dirac-delta

I want to calculate the summation over integers of the product of two shifted sinc functions:

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(n-a)\operatorname{sinc}(n-b) $$

where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ is the normalized sinc function:

$$ \operatorname{sinc}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\operatorname{sin}(\pi x)}{\pi x} & \text{if } x \ne 0 \\ 1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I'm quite sure that the sum evaluates to $\operatorname{sinc}(b-a)$ (I checked this numerically), but I cannot figure out how to prove it.

The following are some approaches I tried:

- Writing the sum as $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(n)\operatorname{sinc}(n-(b-a))$; only the term at $n=0$ is non-zero. But how can I show that both sums are equivalent?
- Writing the sum as an integral sampled at integers, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(x-a)\operatorname{sinc}(x-b) \Delta(x) dx$, where $\Delta(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-n)$ is the Dirac comb. Using the Fourier transform the integral can be written as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{e^{-ia\omega}\operatorname{rect}(\frac{x}{2\pi}) * e^{-ib\omega}\operatorname{rect}(\frac{x}{2\pi}) * \mathcal{F}\{\Delta(x)\}\} dx$, where $*$ represents convolution. How do I evaluate the integral?
- It's easy to see that the integral version of the sum is $\operatorname{sinc}(b-a)$ (as shown [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/sinc-functions-orthogonality.374350/)), but how do I relate the discrete sum to the integral? Can I use the Euler-MacLaurin formula for this, and if so, how? (I am not familiar with the topic.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\chi$ be the characteristic function on the unit interval $T=[-1/2,1/2]$, and take the Fourier transform to be the form
$$F(f)(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi x}dx$$
then
$$F(\chi)(\xi)=\mathrm{sinc}(\xi).$$
With the modulation to translation property of the Fourier transform you get
$$F(e^{2\pi iax}\cdot\chi)(\xi)=\mathrm{sinc}(\xi-a),\quad F(e^{2\pi ibx}\cdot\chi)(\xi)=\mathrm{sinc}(\xi-b),$$
which means $\{\mathrm{sinc}(n-a)\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$,$\{\mathrm{sinc}(n-b)\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ are Fourier coefficients of $e^{2\pi iax}\cdot\chi$ and $e^{2\pi ibx}\cdot\chi$ in their Fourier expansions respectively.

Now since the exponential basis $\{e^{2\pi inx}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is an ONB on $L^2(T)$, the sum in OP is an $\ell^2$ inner product with respect to this ONB, and with the Plancherel theorem it leads to
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\mathrm{sinc}(n-a)\mathrm{sinc}(n-b)=\int_Te^{2\pi i(a-b)x}dx=F(e^{2\pi i(a-b)x}\cdot\chi)(0)=\mathrm{sinc}(b-a)=\mathrm{sinc}(a-b)$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm not familiar with the concepts employed in the last part of your answer - Plancherel theorem, $\ell^2$ inner products, basis functions etc. - could you point me to a textbook or just general keywords on where to understand these concepts?

Comment: Perhaps you could try Chapter 8 in Real Analysis by Folland, and do exercise 15 in that chapter, it is a classic textbook.

Comment: Just to check my understanding: Suppose $sinc^{(p)}(x)$ is the p'th derivative of sinc(x), then by the same approach $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \operatorname{sinc}^{(p)} (n-a) \operatorname{sinc}^{(q)} (n-b)$ would equal $\int_T (-ix)^p e^{2\pi iax} (ix)^q e^{-2\pi ibx} dx$, correct? Which, if I evaluate correctly, is $(-1)^q \operatorname{sinc}^{(p+q)} (a-b)$? (Asking here because I wasn't sure if this is worth a new SE question)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another proof of the identity
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(n-a)\operatorname{sinc}(n-b)=\operatorname{sinc}(a-b). \tag{1}
$$
We start with the definition of the sinc function:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{sinc}(n-a)\operatorname{sinc}(n-b)
&=\frac{\sin \pi(n-a)}{\pi(n-a)}\frac{\sin \pi(n-b)}{\pi(n-b)} \\
&=\frac{\sin \pi a\, \sin \pi b}{\pi^2(n-a)(n-b)} \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{n-a}-\frac{1}{n-b}\right)\frac{\sin \pi a\, \sin \pi b}{\pi^2(a-b)}. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Now, combining $(2)$ with the identity$^{(*)}$
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+x}=\frac{1}{x}+2x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-n^2}=\pi\cot\pi x, \tag{3}
$$
we may rewrite the sum on the LHS of $(1)$ as
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(n-a)\operatorname{sinc}(n-b)&=
\pi(-\cot\pi a+\cot\pi b)\frac{\sin \pi a\, \sin \pi b}{\pi^2(a-b)} \\
&=\frac{-\cos\pi a \sin\pi b+\cos\pi b\sin\pi a}{\pi(a-b)} \\
&=\frac{\sin\pi(a-b)}{\pi(a-b)}=\operatorname{sinc}(a-b).\quad\square \tag{4}
\end{align}

---

$^{(*)}$I. S. Gradshteyn and S. M. Ryzhik, [*Table of Integrals, Series, and Products* (7th Ed.)](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf), formula 1.421.3.